# Why does replace with $$ only results in $

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Tested the code in Chrome 52

```
   var a = "$$";
   var b = "{data}";
   var result = b.replace("{data}", a);
   console.log(result);
```

The result should be "`$$`", but console.log shows "`$`".

Why is there one `$` instead of two `$$`?

Comment: use `var a = "$$$$"` for `double dollar` as a replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

… because a `$` has special meaning in a replacement string, and `$$` how you represent a literal `$`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) for a list of such special sequences.

Answer (score 5):

Because `$$` is a special token in `replace` replacement strings. In `replace` replacement strings, `$` is an escape character ([more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)). To actually put `$$` in the string, use `$$$$`.

Here's the series of `$` sequences that can be used:

- `$$` - Inserts a `$`.
- `$&` - Inserts the matched substring.
- `` $` `` - Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.
- `$'` - Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.
- `$n` Where n is a non-negative integer lesser than 100, inserts the nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a RegExp object.

Here's an example using all of them:

```js
var str = "This is a test.";
console.log(str.replace(
   /\b(is) a\b/,
  "[[\n" +
  "Dollar sign: $$\n" +
  "Matched: $&\n" +
  "Before: $`\n" +
  "After: $'\n" +
  "Captured: $1\n" +
  "]]"
));
```

Comment: Actually `$$$` is enough for `$$` replacement.

Comment: @GinoPane: Meh, I prefer not to roll those dice. Suppose you don't control the character that follows, and the character that follows happens to be a valid sequence completion like `1`? Much better to use complete sequences, not half-complete ones.